# Possible to make a div independent of other styles

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add some Social share buttons (facebook, twitter, etc.) to a blog without using a plugin, and am having an extremely hard time getting them to align vertically, and I know it's because the Wordpress styles are interfering because I was able to get the buttons to work on non-WP pages.

Is there some way to create a div that tells the browser "don't apply ANY styles to this div other than the ones I declare specifically for it, and if I don't declare any, don't apply any."

Comment: The only way is to change every property you don't like, I think.

Comment: Don't know the answer but got a little tip for you: Open the web page with google chrome, right click the button and Inspect element, chrome should list all the styles that are applied to it, and you should just reverse them in your CSS

Comment: We need the stylesheet and some example code if you want us to do anything.

Comment: @Lime - Here's a URL: http://www.datesphere.com/blog/2011/06/07/help-us-grow/ . The problem I'm having is the buttons are generated via javascript and I can't change their styles, which are called from stylesheets hosted by facebook, etc. that I don't control. @Omer - I know about Dev tools and have been using them, but am still stumped. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the `div` its own class, something like `socialButtons` and then start by removing the `margin`, `padding`, `border`, and `float`

```
div.socialButtons{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    float:none;
}
```

In most instances, that should be enough.  If not, you can progressively remove other styles.

Make sure you place this at the bottom of your stylesheet so that your rules take precedence over other rules.

Comment: I actually figured it out just now. The Digg button was causing all the problems, and I found a parameter that lets you disable the default styles and declare your own. Thanks anyway guys!

Answer (score 1):

You should use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) (an addon for firefox) which will tell you every style applied to the div. then use inline css to set every value to its default. to find default values use the [w3schools tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) and look at the different attribute's pages. if you dont want to use inline css, you can make a class or id at the bottom of your linked css file (make sure it is at the bottom so it taks precedent over other styles).

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the styles for that div to their default by specifying every key and its default value, and then restyle it to your liking (kind of like how the reset.css works if you've heard of it)

Comment: For a better chance at getting marked up or even correct, you should supply a snippet example of what you are suggesting - in case the user isn't CSS experienced.